Custom Captcha validation on the registration form issue
I made myself a custom CAPTCHA SUM type and it's working , however even if I add the right sum, my customer will not be created, not sure why and how to debug this.
Here is my code:
The wp-content/plugins/custom-sum-captcha/custom-sum-captcha.php content is:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Sum CAPTCHA
Description: Custom CAPTCHA requiring users to solve the sum of two random numbers.
Version: 1.0.0
Author: XXXXXXXXXXX
*/
// Enqueue JavaScript file
// Enqueue jQuery and define ajaxurl
function custom_sum_captcha_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-sum-captcha-script', plugins_url('js/captcha.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    // Define ajaxurl variable for the frontend
    wp_localize_script('custom-sum-captcha-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_sum_captcha_enqueue_script');

// Validate CAPTCHA
function custom_sum_captcha_validate_answer($answer) {
    $sum = intval($_POST['real_answer']);
    $user_answer = intval($answer);
    return $user_answer === $sum;
}
// Callback function to handle AJAX request
function custom_sum_captcha_validate() {
    // Check if the request is a POST request
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Check if the answer is provided
        if (isset($_POST['captcha_answer'])) {
            // Validate the CAPTCHA
            $is_valid = custom_sum_captcha_validate_answer($_POST['captcha_answer']);

            // Send JSON response
            echo json_encode($is_valid ? '1' : '0');
        }
    }
    // Always exit to prevent further execution
    wp_die();
}

// Hook the AJAX action
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_sum_captcha_validate', 'custom_sum_captcha_validate');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_sum_captcha_validate', 'custom_sum_captcha_validate');


// Generate CAPTCHA HTML
function custom_sum_captcha_generate_html() {
    $num1 = rand(1, 10);
    $num2 = rand(1, 10);
    $sum = $num1 + $num2;

    $html = '<p>Please solve the following math problem:</p>';
    $html .= '<p>' . $num1 . ' + ' . $num2 . ' = <input type="text" id="captcha-answer" name="captcha-answer" style="width:20%"/></p>';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" id="captcha-sum" value="' . $sum . '" />';
    return $html;
}

// Shortcode handler
function custom_sum_captcha_shortcode() {
    return custom_sum_captcha_generate_html();
}
add_shortcode('custom_sum_captcha', 'custom_sum_captcha_shortcode');


function custom_sum_captcha_validate_registration($errors) {
    echo 1212; exit();
    // Validate the CAPTCHA answer
    if (empty($_POST['captcha-answer']) || !custom_sum_captcha_validate_answer($_POST['captcha-answer'])) {
        // CAPTCHA validation failed, add an error message
        $errors->add('captcha_error', __('The CAPTCHA answer is incorrect.', 'textdomain'));
    }
    return $errors;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 'custom_sum_captcha_validate_registration', 10, 1);

the wp-content/plugins/custom-sum-captcha/js/captcha.js content is:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.woocommerce-form-register').on('submit', function(event) {
        // Prevent form submission
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get the email input value
        var userEmail = $('#reg_email').val();

        // Validate email format
        if (!isValidEmail(userEmail)) {
           alert('Error message 1');
            return; // Exit the function
        }

        // Get the user's answer
        var userAnswer = $('#captcha-answer').val();
        var realAnswer = $('#captcha-sum').val();

        // Check if the answer is empty
        if (userAnswer.trim() === '') {
            alert('Error message 2');
            return; // Exit the function
        }

        // Send AJAX request to validate the CAPTCHA
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'custom_sum_captcha_validate',
                captcha_answer: userAnswer,
                real_answer: realAnswer
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Response from server:', response); // Log the response from the server
                if (response && response === '1') {
                    alert('OK');
                    // If the answer is valid, submit the form
                    $('.woocommerce-form-register').off('submit').submit();
                } else {
                    // If the answer is invalid, display an error message
                    alert('Error message 3');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Log any errors that occur during the AJAX request
                console.error('AJAX Error: ', xhr.responseText);
                alert('An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.');
            }
        });
    });
    // Function to validate email format
    function isValidEmail(email) {
        var emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        return emailRegex.test(email);
    }
});

This is the child-theme file:
wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php content:
<form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
                    </p>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

                    <p class="form-row">
                        <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
                            <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                        </label>
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit<?php if ( fl_woocommerce_version_check( '7.0.1' ) ) { echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); } ?>" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                    </p>
                    <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                    </p>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

                </form>

My form is submitted when I add the right sum of my captcha and i receive an alert if not. So far so good. But after the form submit , after I add my email address, my user is not created. Can anyone tell me why ? how to debug this more ?
Thank you

I think i over complicated a bit :)
using this hook woocommerce_register_post would simply things.
This is my content of the custom-sum-captcha.php file:
function custom_sum_captcha_generate_html() {
    $num1 = rand(1, 10);
    $num2 = rand(1, 10);
    $sum = $num1 + $num2;

    $html = '<p>Please solve the following math problem:</p>';
    $html .= '<p>' . $num1 . ' + ' . $num2 . ' = <input type="text" id="captcha-answer" name="captcha-answer" style="width:20%"/></p>';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" id="captcha-sum" name="captcha-sum" value="' . $sum . '" />';
    return $html;
}

// Shortcode handler
function custom_sum_captcha_shortcode() {
    return custom_sum_captcha_generate_html();
}
add_shortcode('custom_sum_captcha', 'custom_sum_captcha_shortcode');

// Validate CAPTCHA on registration form submission

function custom_sum_captcha_validate_registration_form($username, $email, $validation_errors) {
    // Check if the CAPTCHA answer is provided
    if (empty($_POST['captcha-answer'])) {
        $validation_errors->add('captcha_error', __('Please enter the CAPTCHA answer.', 'textdomain'));
    } else {
        // Validate the CAPTCHA answer
        $captcha_answer = intval($_POST['captcha-answer']);
        $real_answer = intval($_POST['captcha-sum']);
        if ($captcha_answer !== $real_answer) {
            $validation_errors->add('captcha_error', __('The CAPTCHA answer is incorrect.'.$captcha_answer.'---'.$real_answer, 'textdomain'));
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'custom_sum_captcha_validate_registration_form', 10, 3);

And i have added <?php echo custom_sum_captcha_generate_html(); ?> in the form-login.php file
and that's it ! no more js , no more ajax
